# Not able to delete a particular row

Tags: java, html, jsf, arraylist, popup

I am trying to delete a particular row from a table in an arraylist. This is the HTML code

```
<h:outputLink styleClass="delete_link" value="#delete" >Delete</h:outputLink>

     <a href="#delete" class="overlay" id="delete"></a>
                    <div class="popup">

                               <p style="font-size: 20px;">Are you sure you want to delete <b><h:outputText size="15" value="#{abc.name}" /></b> from the  <b><h:outputText size="15" value="#{xyz.userlist}"/></b> List</p>

                        <div>
                              <h:commandButton id="submit-button2" styleClass="click_button1"
                                type="submit" value = "No, do not delete #{xyz.name} from #{abc.userlist}"  action="userlist.jsf?faces-redirect=true" update="msgs" /> 

                                                                            <br></br>
                              <h:commandButton id="submit-button1" styleClass="click_button2" style="background:green; color:white;"
                                type="submit" value = "Yes Delete"  action="#{xyz.deleteAction(o)}" update="msgs" /> 
                        <br /> <a class="close" href="#close"></a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

and this is the java code

```
    public String deleteAction(userlist order) {
    int index1 = orderList.indexOf(order); 
    orderList.remove(index1);
    return null;
    }
```

The problem I am facing here is that every time I delete a row, the first row gets deleted and the value of index also comes out to be 0. 
Earlier when I used the same function without the pop-up, it was working fine.

Comment: So, the `equals()` method of `userlist` class is broken in such way that it immediately matches the first item of `orderList` instead of the matching item?

Comment: @BalusC - Basically when this html page gets loaded, it automatically sets the value of index1 as 0 irrespective of row I have selected and this is because of the abc.name or xyz.name present in the popup box which automatically gets the value when this html page is loaded

Comment: It appears that you have no idea how `indexOf()` works under the covers. It is using `equals()` method of `userlist` for that. It iterates over every item until `equals()` method returns `true` for the currently iterated item and then returns the current iteration index. Do you have any idea what the `equals()` method does and how it should be implemented? Your problem suggests that it's wrongly implemented.